# Redirect Domain X to site on Domain Y, but make it look like the site is on Domain X

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, hosting

I'm not sure if this is possible. Not too familiar with Mod Rewrite.

I have domain1.tld registered on a hosting company and then I'm hosting a website on domain2.tld. I have forwarded domain1.tld and masked it. It works fine. Now I want domain2.tld to also show domain1.tld if I type it into the address bar.

It's running a WordPress site, so all my links are domain2.tld/link, but it only displays domain1.tld and my favicon also is gone. Is there a way I can get around this or would it be better to set up a hosting account where domain1.tld is registered, move the website there and redirect domain2.tld to domain1.tld. This would definately be the quickest and easiest way. I cannot point domain1.tld to domain2.tld or transfer it as the host does not support this TLD.

Comment: This sounds a bit "chicken and egg"? ...`domain1` shows the content of `domain2` in a frame (ie. masked), but you also want `domain2` to show `domain1`?! Sorry, you lost me?

Comment: It sounds a bit confusing without names. Basically I want to host the website content on domain2.net but people must search for and type in domain1.com in their address bar or search engine. It must be as if the website content is on domain1.com. The reason I'm not doing this is because I would have a hosting account with a dead domain with company1 and I'll need to register a new hosting accunt with company2  as I only have domain1.com registered and parked with them. Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your account at `domain2.net` does not support additional "Addon" or "Parked" domains (possible with some cPanel or maybe Plesk accounts)? I'm not sure whether a restriction on the TLD would apply here, since you're not "transferring" anything, just changing NAMESERVER or A records?

> would it be better to set up a hosting account where domain1.tld is registered, move the website there and redirect domain2.tld to domain1.tld

Otherwise... Yes, that would certainly be a preferable solution.

If not, you are still going to need some kind of hosting account at `domain1.tld` from which you can forward requests (as a *reverse proxy*) to `domain2.tld`. Using "masked" (or "framed") forwarding is not a particularly good solution, as you have found. However, acting as a *reverse proxy* would require some configuration at `domain1.tld`, and depending on the next bit (see below) this might require more configuration.

> so all my links are domain2.tld/link

If you want your site to be displayed at `domain1.tld` then this is something you would need to resolve. Can you make the links root-relative? Does WordPress need to know the domain/host on which it is running?

It is possible that the *reverse proxy* can handle this (ie. changing the link URLs in the HTML), but this requires more configuration. Or, you can roll your own proxy server.

But this all involves you having a hosting account (with some capability) anyway, so you might as well host your site there to begin with?

Comment: The quickest resolve would be to create a new hosting account yes. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly the preferred solution. If this answered your question, then please mark it as "accepted" (checkmark on the left), to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated :)